# How to loop through a firestore array and get a specific item

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a function to calculate the total price in my shopping cart. I have made it so that the "cost" value will be the "price" value times the "quantity" value. I am now trying to grab the "cost" values from all the different cart items and add them together to get the total price for my cart. How should I do this; I am not sure of how to loop through the different items.

[image: Firestore Database]

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not support [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) as of now. You will have to fetch that document and calculate the total yourself from the Cart array.

Alternatively, you can store the total in a separate field in that document and keep it updated every time an item is added/remove from the cart using [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#transactions).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Cart field is designed as a Firestore Array so when you read the specific cart doc you can simply do the following (example in JS):

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userDocId).get()
  .then(doc=> {
    let total = doc.data().Cart.reduce((sum,item)=> sum += item.cost,0);
  });
```